# Merging two data frames

Tags: r

I have a data frame like with more samples like

```
> head(a[1:2,1:4])
             ID               ids pre.or.post.treatment
1 OCCAMS/AH/120 LP6005409-DNA_F01                   pre
2 OCCAMS/AH/126 LP2000325-DNA_A01                   pre
            TRG
1 non-responder
2 non-responder
> dim(a)
[1] 160   4
>
```

Another data frame with part of my samples but more characteristics for each sample like

```
> dim(b)
[1] 60 50

> head(b[1:2,1:6])
             ID       TRG pre.or.post.treatment          ID.1
1 OCCAMS/AH/212 responder                   pre OCCAMS/AH/212
2 OCCAMS/AH/279 responder                   pre OCCAMS/AH/279
  DiagnosisDate FE.LastSeenDate
1      8/8/2013        6/6/2014
2     6/10/2014       11/8/2018
>
```

How I can  merge these data frame getting a new data frame with my all 160 samples columns of both a and b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your column ID in both dataframes `a` and `b` shared same IDs, and as your dataframe are not particularly heavy, you can have the use of the function `left_join` from `dplyr` package as this:

```r
library(dplyr)
DF <- left_join(a,b, by = "ID")
```

Answer (score 3):

@dc37's dplyr solution is quite elegant, but you can also use base R's merge:

```
merge(x = df_a, y = df_b, by = "ID", all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)
```

You can tweak various parameters, such as use `by.x` and `by.y` instead of just `by`, change `all.x` and `all.y` based on requirements to get your results.

This is a pretty common R question by the way, and if you had googled "merging data frames", you'd see a lot of options.